# How to show the select arrow image on selected cell in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-cell

I have `tableView with custom cell` that is working fine but when I select the button it shows selected image other wise simple box image .

**problem: when i select any cell it also selets any other cell and shows that cell button image selected.Here is my code**

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
         if (tableView == employeeTableView)
         {
              employeeCell = (EmployeeCell *)[employeeTableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
              if (!employeeCell) 
              {
                   employeeCell = [[EmployeeCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
                   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmployeeCell" owner:self options:nil];

                   employeeCell = (EmployeeCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
              }

        employeeTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        employeeTableView.backgroundView=nil;
        employeeCell.emplyeeName.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        employeeCell.employeeDepartement.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        employeeCell.EmployeePosition.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
        Coffee *coffeeObj=[appDelegate.employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        employeeCell.employeeDepartement.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
        employeeCell.EmployeePosition.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

        employeeCell.emplyeeName.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

        employeeCell.emplyeeName.text = coffeeObj.employeeName;
        employeeCell.EmployeePosition.text = coffeeObj.employeeJob;
        employeeCell.employeeDepartement.text = coffeeObj.departmentName;

        if ([employeeCell.selectionButton isSelected]) 
        {
            employeeCell.selectedImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckArrow"];

        }
        else
        {
             employeeCell.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boxbutton"];
        }
        [employeeCell.selectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(setSelectCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [employeeCell.selectionButton setTag:indexPath.row];

        return employeeCell;

    }

    if (tableView == trainerTableView)
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [trainerTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Calvin Banks";
//      [appDelegate.trainerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
 }
    return 0;

}


    -(void)setSelectCell:(id)Sender
    {
     CGPoint point =[Sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:employeeTableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath =[employeeTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
     NSLog(@"indexPath %@",indexPath);
     Coffee *cofee;

     cofee = [appDelegate.employeeArray objectAtIndex:[Sender tag]];

     employeeCell =(EmployeeCell *)[employeeTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([employeeCell.selectionButton isSelected]) {
        [employeeCell.selectionButton setSelected:NO];

        employeeCell.selectedImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"boxbutton"];

    }
    else
    {
        [employeeCell.selectionButton setSelected:YES];
        employeeCell.selectedImage.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckArrow"];

        [selectedEmployees addObject:cofee];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one :

//take it in .h file mutable arSelectedRows;

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell56756";
if (tableView == employeeTableView)
{
   EmployeeCell *Cell  = (EmployeeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (Cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EmployeeCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentobject in topLevelObject)
        {
            if ([currentobject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                Cell = (EmployeeCell *) currentobject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    employeeTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    employeeTableView.backgroundView=nil;


    Cell.emplyeeName.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    Cell.employeeDepartement.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    Cell.EmployeePosition.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];

    Cell.employeeDepartement.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    Cell.EmployeePosition.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];
    Cell.emplyeeName.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    Coffee *coffeeObj=[appDelegate.employeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell.emplyeeName.text = coffeeObj.employeeName;
    Cell.EmployeePosition.text = coffeeObj.employeeJob;
    Cell.employeeDepartement.text = coffeeObj.departmentName;

    if([arSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        Cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        Cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return Cell;

}
if (tableView == trainerTableView)
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [trainerTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Calvin Banks";
    return cell;
  }
   return 0;
}
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if (tableView == employeeTableView)
   {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           [arSelectedRows addObject:indexPath];
        }
        else {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
           [arSelectedRows removeObject:indexPath];
      }
      NSLog(@"id are here :%@",arSelectedIDs);
    }

     [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

 }
```

it will help .

happy coding ...

Comment: I am not asking this is for the accessory type i have given custom cell